# Google drive dredit example

Tags: google-drive-api

I can't run the of dredit example for PHP, as you can see here i can't grant access to the app, always do a redirect to auth:

http://drivecrypt.sofistic.net

any suggestions?

thanks

Comment: What errors are logged on the server while the client is seeing this looping?

Comment: 302 2262 "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file+https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile+https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email&client_id=171645451779.apps.googleusercontent.com&response_type=code&access_type=online&redirect_uri=https://drivecrypt.sofistic.net/&state={%22action%22:%22create%22}" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.19 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/18.0.1025.168 Safari/535.19".......just that entry at apache log.

Answer (score 1):

Did you follow all setup steps listed at https://developers.google.com/drive/examples/php#setting_up_this_sample_application?

More specifically, did you register your app (step 2) and create a listing for it on the Chrome webstore (step 3)?

Comment: yes i do, referer to that, in this list there 2 scopes https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email and https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile but in redir url i have one more, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file, i add this scope to the api conf because is something that makes sense

Comment: p.s. you shouldn't add the drive.file scope in the API console, this scope is added automatically.

Comment: what about app listing? is mandatory to publish (and pay 5 bucks) to develop de app? one friend have a develop account, he publish the app, is he and only he who can setup the rigth oauth config (api console and edit config)?

Comment: I do some changes in url's and auth is running but..... what is this message now?

http://drivecrypt.sofistic.net/

Answer (score 0):

I change access_type=online to access_type=offline and all work again.