# Google Drive SDK asking for permissions

Tags: .net, oauth-2.0, google-drive-api

I have a test app created in .NET with the DrEdit example. I have published this to the testusers group so I can open it in Chromes webstore. But everytime I access it it will ask for permissions "My App is requesting permission to:".

Is this expected behavior or is this a mishap in my .NET app?

Comment: Maybe the same problem like [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10504718/google-drive-dredit-example)?

Comment: No my problem goes further. After already having authenticated AND approved by google the user always has to approve again after. It probably is because of this line:queryParameters.Set("approval_prompt", "force"); but if I leave this out I cannot open files anymore.

Comment: Are you getting the *Approve Permissions* screen each time you request some *resource* from the Google Drive API or each time you call the OAuth *authorization endpoint*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By setting `approval_prompt=force` Google does exactly what they specify in their [documentation](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer#formingtheurl):

> Indicates if the user should be re-prompted for consent. The default is auto, so a given user should only see the consent page for a given set of scopes the first time through the sequence. If the value is force, then the user sees a consent page even if they have previously given consent to your application for a given set of scopes.

So when you set that value, you cannot expect something else.

You should better hunt for the cause of the other problem you're having instead of implementing some workaround without understanding its consequences. If you need help by finding that cause, feel free to post a new question where you provide the *relevant* parts of your code with some context and I'm sure someone can help you with that.

Comment: Yes I have seen this "option". But by removing it you will not be able to read or write any files anymore (error invalid credentials will be returned from the SDK). I have tried a few other apps in the chrome store and they all appear to have the same issue. I assume this is by design then. The documentation does not specify that "approval_prompt=force" can be changed in the Drive SDK.

Comment: Well the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/) doesn't say anything about you having to use that parameter, though they use it in their example. Using that parameter should either way be completely decoupled from accessing ressources as long as you have a valid `access_token` with the right scope.

Comment: Exactly, you would say that! But for some reason it has something to do with eachother. I will post a code example tomorrow, maybe the google team can have a look at it.